# Compute Sum by Rows and Columns (Double series)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

I am trying to solve this problem.

If
$$a_{m,n} = \frac{m-n}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}, (m, n > 0)$$
$$a_{m,0}=2^{-m}, a_{0, n} = -2^{-n}, a_{0, 0} =0,$$
Show that $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right) = -1, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right) = 1$.

Here is my attempt for $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right)$.

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right)= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}.$$ Then, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right) &= 
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{m-n}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}\right]+\frac{1}{2^m}\right) \\ 
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{m}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}\right]-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{n}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!}\right]+\frac{1}{2^m}\right) \\ 
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^m}-1+\frac{1}{2^m} \right) \\ 
&= 0.
\end{align*}

See below about how I get $0$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{m}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!} 
&= \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!n!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{m+n-1 \choose n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n{-m \choose n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \\ 
&= 
\frac{1}{2^m}\left[(1-\frac{1}{2})^{-m}-1\right] (\text{binomial expansion})\\
&= \frac{1}{2^m}\left[2^m-1\right] \\ 
&= 1-\frac{1}{2^m}. 
\end{align*}

Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!} &=
\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!(n-1)!} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{m+n-1 \choose n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n}} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}{-(m+1) \choose n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\frac{1}{2} \\ 
&=\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-(m+1)} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}2^{m+1}\\
&=1. 
\end{align*}
Thus, we have

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right)= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{m,n}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n} = 0-1.$$

I just answer my own question.

Comment: Why aren't the sums equal?  The only difference is the order of summation.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If the double series converges, then those two sums should be the same. Since they are different the double series diverges. In general, they are not equal.

Comment: The equation after "Then we have" doesn't look right.   RHS first term looks like LHS omitting $n=0$.  The next two RHS terms look like the first term split up.  these (2nd and 3rd) terms all have positive elements with convergent sums.  It seems to me you have shown the double sum to be convergent.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The double sum converges but the “double series” diverges since the sum by rows and sum by columns are different. The reason why I split things up is because how they define the term of the series. Maybe I did it wrong when I split it, but you just don’t sound like you know anything about double series at all.

Comment: I see that you made a trivial error for the first summation.  You omitted $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=-1$   (on first line) when you were putting it together.  Try not to be insulting!

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sorry about my language! I did put -1 when I combined thing together. That should be in the last equation shown above.  I got 1/4-1, which is not the correct answer.

Comment: I think I see the basic problem:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(n+m-1)!}{2^{n+m}m!n!}=\frac{1}{4^m}-\frac{1}{2^m}$  The LHS has all positive terms, yet the RHS is negative.  My mistake has been not seeing this error.  In fact the LHS  (after summing over m) is divergent, so my assumption about convergence was incorrect.

Comment: What does $\binom{-m}{n}$ mean?  Factorals for negative integers  are $0$.

Comment: It means $-m$ choose $n$ and it is not always zero. You can always find it in Calculus 2 textbook, under the binomial series section. See below. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/binomialseries.aspx

Comment: In any case your calculation to get $-\frac{1}{4}$  is completely wrong.  You summed a divergent infinite series of positive numbers to get $\frac{1}{4^m}-\frac{1}{2^m}$.

Comment: Can you show me why it is divergent?

Comment: If you use ratio test, it should be convergent because the limit is $0.5$. Remember that $m$ is fixed. I agree the sum is wrong because I didn’t get the right answer.

Comment: Divergence is complicated (I could be mistaken - using Stirling's formula) , but the first terms (in n) are $m/2 +m(m+1)/8$ which is $\gt \frac{1}{2^{-m}}-1$.  Here all terms are positive.  In any case if the series is convergent, then my original answer applies and the double sum of $(m-n)b_{m,n}=0$.

Comment: All I need to prove is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{m-n}{2^{m+n}}\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!n!} = -\frac{1}{2^m}$ and I am done.

Comment: I just saw your mistake - completely trivial!  $(1-\frac{1}{2})^{-m}=2^m$, NOT $2^{-m}$!

Comment: @herbsteinberg I feel like I am an idiot! That totally fixed the whole problem. You’re the genius.

Comment: Finally !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_{m,n}=\frac{(m+n-1)}{2^{m+n}m!n!}$ so $a_{m,n}=(m-n)b_{m,n}$.  Yhe sums $(n=1,\infty),(m=1,\infty)$ and switched, over $mb_{m,n}$ and $nb_{m,n}$ are divergent.  However the sums over $(n-m)b_{n,m}$ are both zero.

The final pieces are $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^m}=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{2^n}=-1$, which cancel.

Comment: But that is still not the correct answer.

Comment: See the Example 2 from page 3 from the following website to see why you can’t interchange the order of double sums in general.      https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~npgallup/m17_mat25/lecture_notes/lecture_15/m17_mat25_lecture_15_notes.pdf

Comment: The description is for conditionally convergent series, where there is a mixture of positive and negative terms.  Here $b_{m,n}\gt 0$ always, so each of the summations is absolutely convergent.

Comment: If you look at the example on that website carefullly, the series for each row or column is also absolutely convergent. Just take the absolutely value on each term, and each series should converge.  But that doesn’t not mean the double series converges. In fact in that example, the double series is divergent since the sum by rows and columns are different.

Comment: Also, it looks like you were trying to compute sum by column and you didn’t get 1.

Comment: The point is that the double series in that example is not absolutely convergent.  The series in each direction has a $-1$ term plus a bunch of positive terms, so that the sum of the absolute values diverges. Each of the double series you have is absolutely convergent.

Comment: In general if a series (single or double) is absolutely convergent, rearranging terms doesn't change the result.  Conditionally convergent series is another story.  That is the essence of the reference.

Comment: I am not going to point out where you did wrong anymore. But you still didn’t get sum by columns = 1.

Comment: I think you should take another look at your original post.  There is a major error which I pointed out above.

Comment: Actually, the first row sum is -1 and every row sum other than the first one is 0. Therefore, the sum by rows is -1. I still haven’t proven it yet but I just put in a calculator, so that should be true.

Comment: Sorry, it should be the $0th$ row that is $-1$ , the row when $m = 0$.

Comment: The rows all add up to $0$, while the columns don't.  Changing $-1$ to $1$ makes it all divergent.

Comment: I totally just proved that the sum by rows is -1 when you pointed out a very trivial mistake I made. Thanks! I might have typo, but it will be minor.